# How to list supported USE flags for virtual package before installation?

Tags: gentoo, ebuild

How to check what USE flags are supported for a **virtual package** pointing to my package, **before** installing it?

Answer (score 1):

Try `equery uses <package-name>`

Comment: This command will tell me what USE flags `package-name` was installed with. What I want to know is what USE flags can `package-name` support **BEFORE** installation.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual packages are somewhat unique in that most of them do not have USE flags. A handful do, and for those `equery uses <package>` will show their USE flags (i.e. `equery uses virtual/pypy`).

For the typical virtual package with no USE flags, the USE flags depend on which package is used to satisfy the virtual, for example `virtual/commonlisp`:

```
% equery use virtual/commonlisp
!!! No USE flags found for virtual/commonlisp-0
```

In this case, you would need to look at what packages could satisfy the virtual, to do this you can use `equery depgraph`:

```
% equery depgraph commonlisp
 * Searching for commonlisp ...

 * dependency graph for virtual/commonlisp-0
 `--  virtual/commonlisp-0  amd64
   `--  dev-lisp/sbcl-1.3.12  (dev-lisp/sbcl) ~amd64
   `--  dev-lisp/clisp-2.49-r100  (dev-lisp/clisp) ~amd64
   `--  dev-lisp/clozurecl-1.11-r1  (dev-lisp/clozurecl) ~amd64
   `--  dev-lisp/cmucl-21a  (dev-lisp/cmucl) [missing keyword]
   `--  dev-lisp/ecls-16.1.3  (dev-lisp/ecls) ~amd64
[ virtual/commonlisp-0 stats: packages (6), max depth (1) ]
```

If you try to emerge a virtual, it will select the first in the list, for example:

```
% emerge -pv 'virtual/cdrtools' && equery depgraph 'virtual/cdrtools'   

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild  N     ] app-cdr/cdrtools-3.02_alpha06-r1::gentoo  USE="acl caps filecaps nls unicode" 2,069 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/cdrtools-0::gentoo  0 KiB

Total: 2 packages (2 new), Size of downloads: 2,069 KiB
 * Searching for cdrtools in virtual ...

 * dependency graph for virtual/cdrtools-0
 `--  virtual/cdrtools-0  amd64
   `--  app-cdr/cdrtools-3.02_alpha06-r1  (app-cdr/cdrtools) ~amd64
   `--  app-cdr/cdrkit-1.1.11-r2  (app-cdr/cdrkit) amd64
[ virtual/cdrtools-0 stats: packages (3), max depth (1) ]
```

In my current portage tree, I only see 59 of 452 virtuals with USE flags. To arrive at this conclusion I counted how many ebuilds in /usr/portage/virtual did not have IUSE="" with `grep -r 'IUSE' /usr/portage/virtual | grep 'ebuild' | egrep -v 'IUSE=""' | wc -l`, then I counted how many ebuilds specified IUSE at all: `grep -r 'IUSE' /usr/portage/virtual | grep 'ebuild' | wc -l`.

Answer (score 0):

eix -A virtual -s wine

or

equery uses virtual/wine